# Working with for loop

Tags: javascript

I need to write a logic where I have 3 months(Jan, feb, march) and between each month I have to add 2 additional values in an array which I will display later. it means that for three months I have to display 7 values(one for Jan, two values between Jan and feb. Simultaneously one value for Feb, and then two values between feb and one for march and so on). in short in between every month, there should be two values. whenever I add an additional month, the value get incremented.

I tried, but not able to complete the logic.I tried for loop as below:

```
int startMonth=1;
int endMonth=3;
var activityMonth=0;
for(int i=startMonth; i<=endMonth;i++
{ 
    activityMonth = activityMonth + 2;
}
for (var j = 0; j <= activityMonth; j++)
    activityTotalMonth.push(j);
```

I wasn't successful in achieving. Can anybody help.

Comment: Is this c# or javascript? And what has jQuery to do with this?

Comment: So, why do you have `jquery` and `c#` tag here?

Comment: actually i wrote the logic under a js file so tagged jquery. i have updated it now.sry abt that

Comment: That doesn't seem C# to me. `push` is a javascript method.

Comment: why all the dislikes :(

Comment: @yash, What are you trying to do? Do you want to create an array for this? or do you want to add an element to this?

Comment: @Abhilash I am just pushing the element to the array and then using this array to dynamically generate the divs. I just wanted to get the correct logic(the correct values) that I have described in my question so that I can add those element in an array and then display the divs

Comment: @Yash, ok, so now you have an array of values, and you want to get each month from this array? is isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int startMonth=1;
int endMonth=3;
var activityMonth=0;
activityMonth =(endMonth-startMonth +1)*3 - 2 ;
```

here is the logic: -2 because your first and last month have only 1 activity.
*3 because there are two activity between two month, so you can consider 3 activity for each month except first and last.

Comment: I know that. the question was how to get the required value.

Comment: In what form you want to get?

Comment: I just want that between each month there should be two values. If I give the start month as Jan and Endmonth as June then the total values that I wanted to push in the array should be 16(two values in between each month)

Comment: instead of your first for loop try activityMonth =(endMonth-startMonth +1)*3 - 2

Comment: Thanks Amit. You've been of great help.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right then this may be your expected solution:

```
var month = ['Jan','Feb','March'];
var newArr = ["single Val"];
var j =0;
for(var i=1; i<(month.length+4)-1; i++){
    if(i%2==0){
        newArr[i] = 'two numbers';
    }else{
         newArr[i] = month[j];
        j++;
    }
}
newArr.push("singleval");
alert(newArr);
console.log(newArr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/21d7dpex/

Comment: Sunil I guess My question is not properly described. Actually I just want the values(say it a number) i.e. the months can be any. between jan to Dec. but whatever starting or ending month there is, the value should be added as a total. for eg. let say startmonth=1(Jan) and endmonth=6(June), then I should get the result as <b>16</b>. this is the sum of total values. value 1 for jan + 2 for (between Jan and Feb)+ 1(feb) + 2(feb and March) +1(March) and so on. So the total is 16